# How can I proxy an ADO Connection object?

Tags: sql-server, com, ado, atl

We have a legacy system built using VC++/VB6 and ASP.NET with C#. The data access is handled in unmanaged code via ADODB which connects to a SQL Server database.

The application connects to the database using a SQL login. Each user has their own SQL login and the system creates a connection using said login for each user.

Due to various security issues, we are trying to move away from SQL logins. But permissions on the DB objects are assigned to the SQL user object. We would like to retain the permission model because changing it would take way too much effort.

So the plan is to *impersonate* the connection to the database via `EXECUTE AS USER='<username>'` by intercepting calls to the `Open` and `Close` methods.

This is where I would like to build a COM object which *pretends* to be an ADO connection object, by implementing the `_Connection` interface that the default ADODB connection object implements.
In my object, I will intercept calls to the `Open` and `Close` methods to handle the impersonation.

This is my sample IDL:

```
...
[uuid(xx-x-x-xx-xxxx), version(1.0), helpstring("xxx")]
library MyComLib
{
   importlib("msado60.tlb");
   [uuid(aa-a-a-aa-aaaa), helpstring("aaa")]
   coclass ImpersonatedConnection
   {
      [default] interface _Connection;
   }
}
```

I plan to expose a new ATL object as follows:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CImpersonatedConnection : 
        public CComObjectRootEx<CComMultiThreadModel>,
        public CComCoClass<CImpersonatedConnection , &CLSID_ImpersonatedConnection>,
        public IDispatchImpl<_Connection, &__uuidof(_Connection), CLSID_MyComLib>,
        public ISupportErrorInfoImpl<&__uuidof(_Connection)>
```

This class holds an internal instance of the *real* `ADODB.Connection` object. All the methods simply forward the call to the real connection.

However, I haven't been able to make this work.

The first issue I have observed is that the DLL does not show this `coclass` when viewed in `OLE object viewer`. Secondly, If I use automation, I get the `Error 430: Class does not support Automation or expected interface...` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For those who are curious I have used an alternative technique in C# by way of a proxy class built with the help of `ImpropmtuInterface` to intercept calls to Open and Close. This works beautifully for code that uses the managed DB access layer.

Comment: Do you have a reproducing project?

Comment: Not at the moment @SimonMourier. But I can spend some time building one if it helps.